# Names for dependencies?

Tags: linear-algebra

There's linear dependence, quadratic dependence and even "cubic dependence" but what is the name of the next "dependence"? Hypercubic dependence?

Comment: Hope you're not gonna ask about 5$^{th}$ order dependency :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either quartic or biquadratic dependency.